# SQL subquery in WHERE returning limited result set but still matching all

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need help with SQL query:

```
UPDATE content_type_blog b
LEFT JOIN node n
ON n.nid = b.nid
SET b.field_is_latest_value = 1
WHERE n.nid IN (
  (
    SELECT nid
    FROM node
    GROUP BY uid
    ORDER BY created DESC
  )
);
```

The select in `WHERE` clause returns 4012 results but when the whole query is run it updates 124k results instead limiting it to those 4012 matched in subquery.

This query intends to update `content_type_blog` - table columns by `nid` where created is highest (latest) in node-table.

Comment: Let's forget about the UPDATE part of the problem. Can you construct a SELECT query capable of returning the desired result? If not, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT. Also, note that OUTER JOINs on UPDATE statements are rare.

Comment: SELECT nid FROM node GROUP BY uid ORDER BY created DESC; does return the neede result set, but for some reason I can't figure the WHERE clause using this dataset allows the UPDATE to update all rows on content_type_blog instead limiting to those returned by subquery.

Comment: I suspect that you need to JOIN that query on 2 conditions if you want it to limit the 4012 update to a specific group.

Comment: If you want to update rows with highest `nid`, then your `where` clause must contain a `max` function.

Comment: I'm trying to update the highest created on result set of nids by uid. The subquery does work as it should but it is not working as limiter for update as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery filters out duplicate `nid` values, but it still returns all of them.  So it's not a filter at all.

In other databases, what you ask is typically done with a window function like `row_number()`.  But MySQL doesn't support that.  Instead, you could use a filtering join.

Here's an example.  SQL Fiddle seems down, so I can't test it, but I hope it will point you in the right direction.

```
create table table1 (col1 int, col2 bit, created datetime)
insert table1 values
    (1, 0, '2013-01-01'),
    (1, 0, '2013-01-02'),
    (1, 0, '2013-01-03'),
    (2, 0, '2013-01-01');

update  table1
join    (
        select  col1
        ,       max(created) as max_created
        from    table1
        group by
                col1
        ) filter
on      filter.col1 = table1.col1
        and filter.max_created = table1.creatd
set     col2 = 1

select  *
from    table1
```

Comment: use id instead of col1

Comment: @Mihai: Thanks, updated.  Didn't use `id` because the OP's `nid` is obviously not unique.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a long way with the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem would be that you are using `content_type_blog b LEFT JOIN`, so doing it you are including all rows of `content_typ_blog` on the result query. Try using `INNER JOIN` to update only the rows of your subquery:

```
UPDATE content_type_blog b
INNER JOIN node n
ON n.nid = b.nid
SET b.field_is_latest_value = 1
WHERE n.nid IN (
  (
    SELECT nid
    FROM node
    GROUP BY uid
    ORDER BY created DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )
);
```

Comment: This does not work:MariaDB [drupal]> UPDATE content_type_blog b
    -> INNER JOIN node n
    -> ON n.nid = b.nid
    -> SET b.field_is_latest_value = 1
    -> WHERE n.nid IN (
    ->   (
    ->     SELECT nid
    ->     FROM node
    ->     GROUP BY uid
    ->     ORDER BY created DESC
    ->   )
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.88 sec)
Rows matched: 120340  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: Are you sure that the subquery does what you want? If you want only the most recent row by `created` column you must limit to 1

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
UPDATE content_type_blog b
LEFT OUTER JOIN node n
ON n.nid = b.nid
JOIN    (
        SELECT DISTINCT nid,
        MAX(created) AS max_created
        FROM    node
        GROUP BY uid
        ) filter
ON      filter.nid = b.nid
SET b.field_is_latest_value = 1;
```

Comment: The `max_created` field is defined but never used, so it doesn't influence the query.  Because you select `nid` without grouping on it, your query will update one random `nid` per `uid`.  I'd test and try a few more solutions :)